# Getting a scrabble score from a word

Tags: c++, strings

My program is complete and runs, and gives me the output I expect. For example, if I enter the string `"HELLO"` I should get `8`. Are there any improvements that can be made?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <cctype> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

int gameScore(string word); 
int letterValue(char ch); 

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        char word[80]; 
        cout << "Enter a word: "; 
        cin.getline(word, 80); 

        if(word[0] == ' ')
            break; 

        int score = gameScore(word);
        cout << "The score for '" << word << "' is " << score << "\n"; 
    }

    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;
}

int gameScore(string word)
{
    int total = 0; 
    int length = word.length(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        total += letterValue(word[i]); 
    }

    return total; 
}

int letterValue(char ch)
{
    int value = 0; 

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 'A': case 'a': 
        case 'E': case 'e':  
        case 'I': case 'i': 
        case 'L': case 'l': 
        case 'O': case 'o': 
        case 'R': case 'r': 
        case 'S': case 's': 
        case 'T': case 't': 
        case 'U': case 'u': 
            value += 1; break; 
        case 'D': case 'd': 
        case 'G': case 'g': 
            value += 2; break; 
        case 'B': case 'b': 
        case 'C': case 'c': 
        case 'M': case 'm':  
        case 'P': case 'p': 
            value += 3; break; 
        case 'F': case 'f': 
        case 'H': case 'h': 
        case 'V': case 'v': 
        case 'W': case 'w': 
        case 'Y': case 'y': 
            value += 4; break; 
        case 'K': case 'k': 
            value += 5; break; 
        case 'J': case 'j': 
        case 'X': case 'x': 
            value += 8; break; 
        case 'Q': case 'q':
        case 'Z': case 'z': 
            value += 10; break; 
    }
    return value; 
}
```

Comment: Are you aware you keep repeating the same mistakes over and over in your questions?

Comment: @Mast I keep using #include <iostream> and using namespce std because my professor requires them in the program codes that are turned in.

Comment: That's not the only thing you're repeating. Are all others also required by your professor?

Comment: @Duck Show these answers to your professer an explain why these things are bad practice.

Comment: system("PAUSE") is something I add in so I can see the output since the VS window closes on me since I am using VS 2010.

Comment: @Duck see my solution to `system("PAUSE");`.

Comment: @EthanBierlein This is for a beginning C++ course so that's why he allows us to use iostream and using namespace std.

Comment: @Duck Just because this is a beginning course doesn't mean it's fine to get into bad habits.

Comment: You post your code here, which indicates you want your code to be good code. If your professor won't allow it, what is the point of us writing answers?

Comment: I apologize if the methods in my codes are not the correct way to do things, but this is the layout the professor has given. Although these are bad habits, they are convenient for the moment. The choice to provide a response or answer is yours. I appreciate the feedback I get.

Comment: This question is [probably being alluded to on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5951/9357).

Comment: `system("PAUSE")` is particularly ugly: it's dangerous and there are n+1 better ways (getc, getchar,cin.get ...)

Answer (score 11):

@Ethan's review already mentioned the basic improvements, but I think that there are other things you could improve and experiment with. At the end of this review I've put together a working example of the refactored code, so you can refer to it for all the things I'm mentioning.

#### A few other nits...

- When your program consists of a single source file, you might as well avoid declaring function prototypes and put the other functions above `main`. This will ease maintenance, since it is one less place to update if you change a function name/parameter type.
- Instead of passing a fixed char array to `getline` and limiting yourself to 80 chars max, you can pass a `std::string` to it and allow for arbitrary length words.
- Make sure to pass the string parameter of `gameScore` as a const reference. In C++, when you pass an object to a function, it will be copied unless stated otherwise. So in that case, `gameScore` is seeing its own copy of the `word`. But you don't need to pay for that copy since the function is only inspecting each character of the string, without modifying it. Enter *references*. When passing a read-only reference, also make it `const` (check the example at the end for the details). It is important to note though that this tip applies to objects only (classes, structs. `std::string` is a class, mind you). Native types like integers and pointers are actually better if passed by value, since the hardware has registers to store them, so copying an `int` into a function is free.
- You did right by storing the length of the string in a local variable inside `gameScore` to avoid calling the method in a loop, but it is actually not a 100% right. Being pedantic, `string.length()` returns an unsigned integer type. You have a few options here to match the type: C++11 and above, use `auto` and let the compiler infer the exact type. Older C++, you can use `std::string::size_type` (if you really love typing `;)`) or shorter, a `std::size_t`, which is equivalent. The only real implication of using `int` like you currently do is that on some platforms it might be smaller than the size of the type returned by `string`, so assuming we are dealing with a Gigabytes long string, it could theoretically truncate the value and loose part of the string's length. Not the case with your program, I'm sure, but it is good to be aware of this when writing portable code.
- Use `const` on local variables that are only assigned/initialized once. For instance, that `int score`. When the scope of a variable is small, it makes little difference, but it is good to get in the habit of using it. When looking at a 100 lines long function, you will be happy to know that the variables you are tracking are not going to be changed after they are declared.

#### An alternate implementation for `letterValue`:

I didn't really like that `switch` in `letterValue`. It is not hard to understand nor unclear, but it just feels too long and verbose...

You could use a Standard [`map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to shorten things up a bit. Map each lower case letter to its integer value, them just lookup the map. If you cast each letter [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) before looking up the map, you don't have to repeat every char for upper and lower case.

#### Sample implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int letterValue(char ch)
{
    // This map replaces your switch/case.
    // The upside is that you don't have to specify
    // upper and lower case letters. The downside is
    // that the letter values have to be repeated 
    // for each entry.
    //
    // Notice that we made it a static constant, so the map
    // doesn't get recreated every time we enter the function.
    //
    // NOTE: To compile this code, you'll need to
    // make sure C++11 support is enabled in your
    // compiler (should be fine by default with recent
    // versions of Visual Studio).
    //
    // Also notice that your solution is missing the entry 
    // for 'n', as was pointed out by Edward in his answer.
    //
    static const std::map<char, int> charValues = {
        {'a',1}, {'e',1}, {'i',1}, {'l',1}, {'o',1},
        {'r',1}, {'s',1}, {'t',1}, {'u',1}, {'n',1},
        {'d',2}, {'g',2}, {'b',3}, {'c',3}, {'m',3},
        {'p',3}, {'f',4}, {'h',4}, {'v',4}, {'w',4},
        {'y',4}, {'k',5}, {'j',8}, {'x',8}, {'q',10}, 
        {'z',10}
    };

    // Since you want to return 0 for a non-mapped letter
    // we first find() it, then check the result. The `? :`
    // thingy is the ternary operator, in case you are not
    // familiar with it. It's just like a compact version
    // of an if then else...
    //
    auto iter = charValues.find(std::tolower(ch));
    return (iter != std::end(charValues)) ? iter->second : 0;
}

int gameScore(const std::string & word) // <= Here you can see the const 
         // reference, to avoid copying the string. The `&` means reference.
{
    // Notice the const here to enforce one-time initialization.
    const std::size_t length = word.length();

    int total = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        total += letterValue(word[i]);
    }

    return total;
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Using a string instead of a fixed size array.
        std::string word;
        std::cout << "Enter a word: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, word);

        // std::string has this handy method to test if it is... Empty!
        if (word.empty())
        {
            break;
        }

        const int score = gameScore(word);
        std::cout << "The score for '" << word << "' is " << score << "\n";
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Nice review! I think you deserve the checkmark. :-)

Comment: Every time `letterValue` is called, `charValues` is created. Every time `letterValue` ense, `charValues` is destroyed. (I think). I think it would be better to move this outside of any functions and to the top of the code. That way, this map will be created at compile time which will make accessing it a lot faster.

Comment: @SirPython, The map is a `static` instance, so it will only be created once the function is entered the first time, lasting until the program quits. That's more or less equivalent of having it as a global, but with the benefit that the name remais at function-level scope. C++11 also guarantees that the first initialization is thread-safe. This answer summarises well the several meanings of `static` in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6223689/1198654

Comment: You're missing an 'n' in the charValues map :) Otherwise, awesome solution.

Comment: @DeeKayy90, right, good point. I just changed the OP's code and didn't catch that. Luckily, Edward's answer already found that error. Edited my code to include the fix ;)

Answer (score 8):

***Remove this line:***

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

This is a horrible, awful habit to get into. So much can go wrong with this line involving name conflicts. After removing this, you should prefix members of the `std` namespace with `std::`. See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more detail.

This line:

> ```
> #include "stdafx.h"
> ```

If you aren't developing an MS-specific app, and you don't need better compile time, especially in something as small as this, this line should be removed.

This line:

> ```
> system("PAUSE");
> ```

Is another bad habit to get into. This line of code is not cross-platform, not optimal, and somewhat insecure as well. Preferably, if you need to see the output, you should do something like this:

```
std::cin.get();
```

This line:

> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Can be removed from `main`. Again, `main` is a special function, so the above line will be automatically inserted.

Finally, you should include a `default` case in your `letterValue` function. For example, what happens if the user enters a character like `$`? To do this, simply add this to the end of your `switch` statement:

```
default:
```

By doing this, you can also remove all the other empty `case`s.

Comment: just a quick question. Is there any reason to use `std::cin.get()` over `getc()` in `cstdio`?

Comment: @James_Parsons `std::cin.get()` doesn't require you to include `<cstdio>`, and it's also just what I'm used to using.

Comment: @James_Parsons `std::cin.get()` is a method from the C++ standard library, while `getc` is from the C library. `std::cin` is more pedantic C++, but both provide the same functionality. Unless you have a good reason to use the C library, stick to the C++ one.

Comment: What empty `case`S?

Comment: @edc65 Go look at the `switch` in the `letterValue` function.

Comment: All of the current cases are used to set a value. No one can be removed just adding `default:`

Answer (score 7):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It is particularly bad to put it into a header file, so please don't do that.

### Don't use `system("PAUSE")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("PAUSE")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `PAUSE` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a separate functions `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++.  For example:

```
void pause() {
    getchar();
}
```

### General portability

This code *could* be made portable if, in addition to the changes in the previous point, you omit the Windows-only include files `#include "stdafx.h"`.

### Use `const` where practical

The passed `std::string` is not modified by `gameScore()` and so it should be declared as `const std::string &`.  Right now, it's passed by value, so the code is making a useless extra copy.

### Use "range-for" to simplify your code

Instead of using an index variable, your for loop could use "range-for":

```
for (const auto &ch : word)
```

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

The code uses "magic numbers" such as 80 that have no obvious meaning.  These would be better as named constants. In this particular case, that constant isn't needed at all.  Just make `word` a `std::string` instead of a fixed size buffer.

### Make it clear when loops end

The code currently uses `while (true)` but it doesn't really loop infinitely.  It's better, generally, to have the loop exit condition explicitly stated.  For example we could rewrite your `main()` function with a helper function and a `for` loop:

```
std::string ask(const std::string &prompt) {
    std::string line;
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    return line;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string prompt{"Enter a word: "};
    for (std::string word = ask(prompt); word[0] != ' '; word = ask(prompt)) {
        std::cout << "The score for '" << word << "' is " << gameScore(word) << "\n"; 
    }
}
```

### Simplify by using appropriate data structure

Rather than doing all of that calculation for each letter, you could use a simple lookup mechanism instead.

```
int letterValue(char ch)
{
    const int points[]{
    //  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  
        1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 
    //  n  o  p  q   r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
        1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10
    };
    return isalpha(ch) ? points[tolower(ch)-'a'] : 0;
}
```

Using that method, you'd have noticed that your existing code has no value for the letter `N`.

### Use a standard algorithm

You could use your existing `gameScore` mechanism, but an even more powerful technique would be to use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with a lambda.  It can be used like this:

```
int gameScore(const std::string &word)
{
    return std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0, [](int total, char a){
        return total + letterValue(a); });
}
```

Since it appears you are just learning the C++ language, this may not make much sense to you yet, but I hope that at least it inspires you to keep learning this powerful and productive language.

Comment: When I transposed the existing code into the form I used, I noticed that there was no value for the letter `N`.  The original code returns a value of 3 for the word `onion` but the correct answer is 5.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your gameScore like:

```
int gameScore(string word)
{
    auto total = int {0};
    for(auto &ch : word)
        total += letterValue(ch);
    return total;
}
```

Hence use for range loop and use `{}` brackets for assignment operation instead of `=`. Use auto even for explicit types.

Comment: Can you explain why this is an improvement over the existing code.

Comment: I'm not seeing many improvements here. For example, how is `auto total = int {0};` an improvement over `int total = 0;`? `auto` is a code smell as well.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am a beginner with C++ but I question what you say @EthanBierlein. Namely I will point you out to [Herb Sutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64), you could also check what Bjarne has to say about it too. I wont argue this point since I am a beginner but I would trust them more than you, sorry. 
As for curly brackets, I have read that in Bjarne's book A Tour of C++ but you can find it on this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) under "Initialization of variables".
Lastly range for loop is also preferred bla bla bla...
BUT DON USE **STD NAMESPACE**!

Comment: @Quill I hope I have addressed some part of your question with my previous answer. 
In addition I have read that you should pass by reference since it is cheaper, and you don't need a copy of passed value. I think this addresses all the points I have made.
I wanted to say that using that switch statement seems unreasonable to me but then again I was downvoted and I though I probably have some serious errors which I don't understand.

Comment: @firtek, you haven't done anything to solve my (and others) concerns about your answer.

Comment: Did you check the links?